Arithmetic progression subsequences issue
I'm trying to solve the following code challenge:

Write a program that reads two integers n and r, both strictly greater than 1, followed by a sequence of integers, and finds out whether the sequence contains a consecutive subsequence of length at least n that forms an arithmetic progression with step r.
A consecutive subsequence of integers forms an arithmetic progression with step r if the difference between two consecutive numbers equals r. For instance, 4 5 6 7 is an arithmetic progression with r = 1, and 22 33 44 55 66 is an arithmetic progression with r = 11.
If the input sequence contains such a progression, the program must print a line with the first n elements in the progression. Otherwise, the program must indicate "No arithmetic progression found with step r and length at least n".
Input
The input consists of two integers n>1 and r>1, followed by a sequence of integers containing at least 2 elements.
Output
If a progression subsequence with reason r and length at least n exists, the output are the first n elements of the progression. Otherwise, the output is "No arithmetic progression found with step r and length at least n".

I have tried with a crappy interpretation of a previous-current scheme but the exercise tester still marks its private tests as wrong answered...
from yogi import scan

n = scan(int)
r = scan(int)
count = 1
found = False
nl = []
prev = -0.1
curr = scan(int)
while curr is not None:
    if curr - prev == r:
        nl.append(prev)
        nl.append(curr)
        count += 1
        if count == n:
            print(*sorted(set(nl)))
            found = True
    prev = curr
    curr = scan(int)

if not found:
    print(f"No arithmetic progression found with step {r} and length at least {n}")


Your example contradicts the requirements. You say "The input consists of two integers n>1 and r>1" yet your example is based on r == 1. Why are you using yogi? If you're not going to check its return values there's no point

Please provide a link to the code challenge site

What's your question? You didn't ask any.

I think the site is regulated by the Universitat Politècnica de Catalunya; it's jutge.org. Sorry for the dumb question and badly structured sentences, I was feeling really down. Thank you guys for the help.

The main problem is that your code never clears nl nor resets count, yet if an arithmetic progression is not long enough yet and broken by curr, you should get rid of the values in nl as they are no longer relevant. By not doing this you risk to print numbers that do not form a consecutive progression.
Some other remarks:

By calling set() and sorted() you try to overcome the problem of introducing duplicates. But it would be better to avoid adding duplicates. Only call append once per iteration: if we are not in an arithmetic progression, then make sure that curr is appended as the only element in nl, already starting a new potential progression. That way you don't ever need to append prev.

When you found a solution, you should break out of the loop, as there is nothing more you need from the input.

It is not necessary to use found. Instead use the else clause of while to report there was no success. (This needs the previous point to be implemented, i.e. there should be a break).

It is not necessary to use count. Instead use len(nl): after fixing the main issue, len(nl) will correspond to your count.

It is not necessary to use prev. Instead use nl[-1]: after fixing the main issue, that will correspond to your prev.


Here is your code with those corrections applied to it:
n = scan(int)
r = scan(int)
curr = scan(int)
# Set a dummy value, making `curr - nl[-1]` equal 0,
#    which will never equal r.
nl = [curr]  
while curr is not None:
    if curr - nl[-1] != r:
       nl.clear()  # discard values that are no longer considered
    nl.append(curr)  # always append the current element
    if len(nl) == n:
        print(*nl)  # no more need to call set(), nor sorted() 
        break
    curr = scan(int)
else:  # if there was no break from the loop (no success)
    print(f"No arithmetic progression found with step {r} and length at least {n}")

